# Java for loop improve performance

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I have a `for` `loop` structure like this:

```
for(T element1 : list1) {
  for(T element2 : element1.getSubElements()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

`list1` contains about 10.000 elements and `element1.getSubElements()` also contains around 10-20 elements for each iteration.

The loop takes around 2 minutes to finish.

Any ideas about how to improve this?

Comment: Profile what's in `...` and see if there is anything to be done there.

Comment: You won't gain much speed in collection parsing, you need to look at the logic that's between the inner set of brackets.

Comment: what are you doing with `element1` and `element2`?

Comment: Sorry! I have an `if`, if the condition is `true` I add the `element2` to an `ArrayList`. Maybe the problem is in the `if`?

Comment: Would make sense for it to be in the `if` condition. Add some timing reports with something like `System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis())` to figure out exactly what method call is taking the most time.

Comment: I guess, you need to show logic of inner for loop too. There might be something else than loops taking time. Also, certain ordering on list might be done to increase performance for your situation. You need to show actual object types of `list1` and `element1.getSubElements()` too.

Comment: You were right guys, the problem are not the loops, it's a database query (android greendao framework) I'm doing inside the loops. Thank you all, I thought the problem were the loops with too many elements but your comments helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The looping doesn't take that long. The work you do in the loop takes the time.

Your options are;

- use a profiler to optimise the work inside the loop.
- use `parallelStream()` to see if doing the work across multiple threads improves the time it takes.

> I have an if, if the condition is true I add the element2 to an ArrayList. Maybe the problem is in the if?

To use parallelStream you can do

```
List<T> list2 = list1.parallelStream()
                     .flatMap(e -> e.getSubElements().stream())
                     .filter(e -> e.isConditionTrue())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Lambda expression](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)

```
list1.forEach(new T<E>() {
    public void accept(E value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
});
```

Actually both the forEach method and the Consumer interface have been added in Java 8, but you can already do something very similar in Java 5+ using libraries like guava  or lambdaj . However Java 8 lambda expressions allow to achieve the same result in a less verbose and more readable way:

```
list1.forEach((E value) -> System.out.println(value));
```

Comment: Note: while you can write it this way, it is highly unlikely that doing this will be faster, and a good chance it will be slightly slower.

Comment: What the deuce? Iterating over collections is cheap. It's the `...` that's expensive in the OP's case.